# SDK location not found libgdx IntelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea, libgdx

Hi I get this error when I try to import my libgdx project:
[image: error]

The thing is, I don't want to develop for android with my libgdx project. How do I remove this dependancy? I also don't want to get an SDK just to have this work because it's uselessly added weight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit `build.gradle` comment/remove the `project(":android") {...}` block.

(Optional) Delete the `android` subfolder